# Java decompiler is not giving full source code

Tags: java, decompiling, jad

I have tried to decompile .class file with [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/). BUt i got Strange code in it(Static call to a non static method, Classname.this.method etc.) .

Could you please tell me whether it will give 100 percent source code or not?

Answer (score 0):

No, java decompilers can't give you the exact source code back. Many compiler optimizations will not be reflected back in the generated file.

Comment: And many different source constructions compile to the same bytecode.

Comment: ...not to mention that within the bytecode you cannot tell apart the use of generics from old-style coding with explicit casts.

Comment: @thkala Not to mention that that is just an instance of what I just said.